# aapt --rename-manifest-package does not work with different AndroidManifest

Tags: android, aapt

I want to build two versions of android application: release version and test with different package names.
I'm using script to build it.
First, generating resource class, with  in AndroidManifest file:

```
aapt package -m -J gen/ --rename-manifest-package <rekease.pkgname> -M ./AndroidManifest.xml -S res_test/ -I <path/to/android-13.jar>
```

This works and generate test version.
After that i tried to use separate AndroidManifest for test version, as it has other name and packagename.
First, i renamed AndroidManifest.xml to AndroidManifest_test.xml and changed it in -M option.

But aapt has written by monkeys and this does not work at all:

```
ERROR: No AndroidManifest.xml file found.
```

Then i placed AndroidManifest to separate directory and used this command:

```
aapt package -m -J gen/ --rename-manifest-package <release.pkgname> -M test/AndroidManifest.xml -S res_test/ -I </path/to/android-13.jar>
```

And it genetated resources, but with , like without --rename-manifest-package option.
How to generate correct class names?

Answer (score 0):

With the new Android Gradle build system, you can easily build multiple different versions of your app; for example, you can build both a "test" version and a "pro" version of your app (using flavors).

You can specify the application id(package name) in your gradle file. You can vary the applicationId of your app for flavors and build types by using the following Gradle DSL methods:

app/build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
    pro {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.pro"
    }
    test {
        applicationId = "com.example.my.pkg.test"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
....
```

Refer [this link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) to know more.